# Rounded Corner of two Label in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, native, rounded-corners

I have two label left and right mentioned .
Now i am trying to rounded the corner from left of left label and right of right label

I have tried this:

```
cell.rightLabel.layer.cornerRadius = UIRectCornerBottomLeft |  UIRectCornerTopLeft;
```

(this code is also not working all border are rounded ..)

```
cell.rightLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

 cell.leftlabel.layer.cornerRadius = UIRectCornerBottomRight | UIRectCornerTopRight;
  cell.leftlabel.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the property `clipsToBounds` to **YES** or use `MasksToBounds` to **YES**

```
cell.rightLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
cell.leftlabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

try this

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.rightLabel.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft ) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        maskLayer.frame = cell.rightLabel.bounds;
        maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
        cell.rightLabel.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: thanks@anbu ...its Working fine .but how to rounded only left side(i.e topleft and buttomleft) of left label and right side(topright and buttomright) of right label

Comment: thanks ...its work fine with one label but if two label are there Left and right are merge then how work with only left side of left label and right side of right label work ..

Comment: @SANTOSH - this line `UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.rightLabel.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft ) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
this one create another one for left side label surely works,

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.label.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft ) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
self.label.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

i hope its work.....